# Can't compile program with regex using clang with libc++

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, linker, clang

I have program with regex. Here is how i'm compiling:

```
clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -H -c <sources> -o <objects>
```

And linking:

```
clang++ <objects> -o <executable>
```

But i'm getting a lot of linker errors about undefined reference to 'std::__1:: ...'. I've read that it's connected with linking between libc++ and libstdc++ but i don't understand how to compile it without linking between them. Could anyone help with this?

clang version 3.5 (trunk 197494)
Target: i386-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix

Comment: `regex` is provided by the C++ standard library, and the one you are using might not have it yet. You might pass `-stdlib=libc++` also at link time.

Comment: thank, i also added -lc++abi option to both compiler and linker flags and now it works.